# Possible period lengths of fractions

Tags: number-theory

I am trying to figure out if all natural numbers can be period lengths of the decimal expansion of some fraction with numerator 1. For example  $\frac{1}{11}$ has period 2, $\frac{1}{37}$ has period 3, $\frac{1}{101}$ has period 4.
I have examples for periods up to 16, but I cannot find such fraction with period 17.

Is there any theory around which are the possible period lengths of such fractions?

Comment: Note that $11$ divides $10^2-1$, $37$ divides $10^3-1$, $101$ divides $10^4-1$. Which number divides $10^{17}-1$?

Comment: For odd denominators $d$, the length of the period of $1/d$ is the multiplicative order of $10 \bmod d$.

Comment: The smallest denominoator giving a period of length $17$ is $2071723$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well,

$$\frac{1}{10^n-1}$$

has period length $n$.

---

To prove this, note that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty 10^{-nk}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty (10^n)^{-k}=\frac{1}{10^n-1}$$

And each $10^{-nk}$ is simply a $1$ with $nk-1$ zeroes before it (so for example, $10^{-2\cdot3}=0.000001$. Five zeroes after the decimal point, and then a $1$).

So for example,
$$\frac{1}{9}=0.111111\cdots$$
$$\frac{1}{99}=0.010101010101\cdots$$
$$\frac{1}{999}=0.0010010010010010010\cdots$$

Comment: Ah... Of course.